# Width of detailTextLabel on cell with UITableViewCellStyleValue2 style

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, multiline

I'm new to stack overflow and to cocoa-touch developing.

I'm trying to build a UITableViewCell using the UITableViewCellSytleValue2 with a multi-line detailTextLabel.

Therefore I implemented the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: like that:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 if (indexPath.row != 4) {
  return tableView.rowHeight;
 }

 NSString *text = toDoItem.note;
 UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
 CGSize withinSize = CGSizeMake(167, 1000);
 CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:withinSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];

 CGFloat height = size.height + 26;

    return height;    
}
```

I figured out the detailTextLabel's width is approximately 167px, but want to know it exactly and don't like it hardcoded (considering orientation changes).

I tried to access the detailTextLabel's frame or bounds, but it returns 0.0 for it's width.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I worked with 200px at a font size of 15. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Cell

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but actually I just don't want to :-). I can't imagine it is not possible to figure out the width of that label, because it obviously has a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could define a static set of variables in a custom implementation of UITableViewCell that sets these sorts of parameters in `layoutSubviews` if and only if not set.  Be sure to call `[super layoutSubviews]` first.</s>

This way you inherit the device defaults, and you never have to wonder.
AFAIK, the cell width is `self.contentView.frame.size.width`.  You can use `self.textLabel.frame.size.width` and `self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width`, and `self.accessoryView.frame.size.width` + padding between each to figure out the details.  I'm not 100% on the padding.  But, you could calculate the padding by detecting the difference between the label widths and contentView frame width.

Sorry.  I forgot the cell's `detailTextLabel` dimensions are always in flux; and definitely not to be relied on period.  You can derive the label width based on the width of the owning UIViewController, and the cells `textLabel`.  Since the calculation is at the controller level, you'll know whether the tableView is grouped.  And if so, you can simply scale the width back by a factor of 0.8 or so, and subtract the `textLabel` width.

Likewise for fonts: `self.textLabel.font.pointSize`, and `self.detailTextLabel.font.pointSize`.